# ǝlzznd ppo ʎɹǝʌ ɐ

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

You received a message. It was as follows:

```
We will add u where necessary, for now solve this on your own: 

01DD01DD02790265028720028E028701DDu1D09u20pu025020p01DD0279pun02652001DDu1D09u

(0), (3)2, (3)2, (11), (16), !(11), (1), (26), (11), (35), !(35), (35), !(1)2, (43), (3)2, (62), !(16), (1), (35)

We will not! add u everywhere, so do not expect it to happen.
```

---

Note that some tags have been removed in order to make the puzzle more difficult.

Comment: Just to check, when you say 'The answer could be anything', there is still a specific correct answer you are expecting to receive, right? This is not an open-ended puzzle?

Comment: @stiv yes, there is only one correct answer. I meant the the answer could either be a number, letter, word, etc.

Comment: Thanks, understood - perhaps you could edit that in as a clarification? Otherwise it sounds like there isn't one specific answer, which mis-sells your puzzle as something looser... Cheers.

Comment: @stiv probably better to just remove it, It's not really needed anyways.

Comment: Your `l` is a little off.

Comment: @JL2210 `l`? where?

Comment: In 'puzz**l**e'.

Comment: @JL2210 blame upsidedowntext.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first string:

> can be divided into groups of 4 or 2 hex digits, and single characters.
>
>  `01DD / 01DD / 0279 / 0265 / 0287 / 20 / 028E / 0287 / 01DD / u / 1D09 / u / 20 / p / u / 0250 / 20 / p / 01DD / 0279 / p / u / n / 0265 / 20 / 01DD / u / 1D09 / u`
>  Converting the hex digits to Unicode characters gives `ǝǝɹɥʇ ʎʇǝuᴉu puɐ pǝɹpunɥ ǝuᴉu`: this reads `nine hundred and ninety three`, written upside down. Turning 993 upside down spells "EGG", which may be the answer you're looking for.

I'm not sure what the second part is - maybe it was supposed to help with the first, and I skipped it?

Comment: rot13(Lbhe nafjre jnf pbeerpg, nygubhtu vg fubhyq whfg fgnl nf "avar uhaqerq naq avargl guerr", sbe "ernfbaf." V jnf guvaxvat nobhg rfpncrq fgevatf, juvpu, va beqre gb harfpncr cebcreyl lbh jbhyq unir gb nqq "h" va pregnva cnegf. V sbetbg gung zbfg bayvar havpbqr qrpbqref qba'g erdhver guvf, znxvat gur chmmyr zhpu rnfvre. Gur frpbaq cneg rffragvnyyl gryyf lbh jurer gb nqq gurfr h'f ohg va pnfr lbh jnag gb svther vg bhg, V jba'g gryy lbh ubj.)